# Java using charAt() with || operator

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to check if there is a consonant in my String.
There error i'm getting is: "Operator || cannot be applied to 'boolean','char'"
Here is my code:

```
       for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
       if(bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b'||'c'||'d'||'f'||'g'||'h'||'j'||'k'||'l'||'m'||'n'||'p'||'q'||'r'||'s'||'t'||'v'||'w'||'x'||'y'||'z'){
        //do something
       }
    }
```

Comment: `bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b' || bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'c'` etc.

Comment: Since you can't chain the OR operator, you'd better create an array (or collection) with all available characters, and test if your collection/array contains this character

Comment: actually expression `bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b'` manipulated to boolean and all other expressions are char. that's why its giving error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `||`, you need to write out the conditions fully:

```
if (bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b' || bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'c'
    || bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'd' ...
```

Or you could find a way to express it more concisely:

```
if ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".indexOf(bezeichnung.charAt(i))>=0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: `"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".contains(bezeichnung.charAt(i))` will not compile, as neither a `char` (nor a `Character`) is  a `CharSequence`.

Comment: @JacobG. then `"".indexOf(char) >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the code the same style you have it, you'd have to do

```
   for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
   if(bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b'|| bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'c'||bezeichnung.charAt(i) =='d) // continue this for all your cases 
    //do something
   }
}
```

If you have to have a long conditional statement like this- I would investigate other ways to accomplish the task you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you may use regular expressions instead.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    String regex = ".*[a-zA-Z].*";
    if(bezeichnung.charAt(i).matches(regex)){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use OR operator like that.

For each character you have to check the condition seperately.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
       if(bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'b' || bezeichnung.charAt(i) ==  'c' || bezeichnung.charAt(i) ==  'd' || bezeichnung.charAt(i) == 'f')
       {
          //do something
       }
 }
```